# Record stockfish level 8 in atomic?

Tags: chess-variants, stockfish, atomic-chess

What is the shortest possible game against Stockfish at its hardest setting in
[Atomic Chess](https://lichess.org/variant/atomic)? You cannot allow the computer to blunder the game on move 1 or 2, otherwise the shortest possible game is 3 moves.